# Cannot run DIND for GCloud SDK docker image in GitLab Runner

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have set up a simple `.gitlab-ci` file which should be able to run docker service:

```
docker:
  image: google/cloud-sdk:latest
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://127.0.0.1:2375
  services:
    - docker:dind
  tags:
    - docker
  script:
    - docker pull buster-slim
```

However it fails as:

https://gitlab.com/knyttl/runnerdemo/-/jobs/932204050

```
2020-12-25T19:31:04.558361767Z time="2020-12-25T19:31:04.558195638Z" level=info msg="API listen on [::]:2375"
2020-12-25T19:31:04.558522591Z time="2020-12-25T19:31:04.558447616Z" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
```

The service apparently correctly starts, but then it doesn't work:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://127.0.0.1:2375. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the only reason why this was not working was:

> DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375

The `dind` service CAN run within `cloud-sdk` image, but it needs to be linked as a `host`.

Comment: This also worked for me in GitLab.

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from the fact that the docker daemon is not part of the image `google/cloud-sdk/` that you specify for this job. You should create your own image with the google/cloud-sdk as a base image. You can also install & start docker in the `before_script` section of the job. See the [doc on DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/r/google/cloud-sdk/) for the image you use:

*Installing additional components*

*By default, all gcloud components are installed on the default images (google/cloud-sdk:latest and google/cloud-sdk:VERSION).
The google/cloud-sdk:slim and google/cloud-sdk:alpine images do not contain additional components pre-installed.*

*You can extend these images by following the instructions below:
Debian-based images*

```
cd debian_slim/
docker build --build-arg CLOUD_SDK_VERSION=159.0.0
    --build-arg INSTALL_COMPONENTS="google-cloud-sdk-datastore-emulator" \
    -t my-cloud-sdk-docker:slim .`
```

Answer (score 1):

The image which can use DIND is `docker:dind`, not necessarily `google/cloud-sdk:latest`, so your `.gitlab-ci.yml` wuold look like:

```yaml
docker:
  image: docker:dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  services:
    - docker:dind
  tags:
    - docker
  script:
    - docker pull buster-slim
    # ...
    # I don't know what needs to be built...
```

You can check this [tutorial](https://haseebmajid.dev/blog/dind-and-gitlab-ci) for a step by step recipe.